# Copy FDMemtable to FDTable , structure and data

Tags: delphi, firedac

What is the shortest coding way to

- create a normal FDTable inside an existing database from an existing
  FDMemtable
- only copy  the data from an FDMEmtable to an  existing     FDTable

I create my FDMemtable from a text file like this, I want to reuse the  existing fielddef information and transfer it to the FDTable (using MSSQL server)

```
function LoadFDMemoryTable( ..... ): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
  /// <summary>
  /// a list  with all the data
  /// </summary>
  FReport: TMyReport;
begin
  ///
  /// define mem table
  ///
  with aFDMemTable do
  begin
    FieldDefs.Add('Index', ftInteger, 0, False);
    FieldDefs.Add('Type', ftString, 0255, False);
    ......

    CreateDataSet;
  end;

  ///
  /// Load data ...
  ///

  ....  
  try

    FReport.LoadFromFile(Reportfile);

    for I := 0 to FReport.Count - 1 do
    begin

      ReportItem := TReportItem(FReport.Items[I]);

      with aFDMemTable do
      begin
        Open;
        Append;

        Fields[0].AsInteger := FReportItem.FImageIndex;
        Fields[1].AsString := ....

        
        Post;
      end;
    end;

  finally

    result := FReport.Count;

    FReport.Free;

  end;

end;
```

Comment: Did you think about FDBatchMove ?